# What is the relation between those two linear equations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions

I'm trying to solve this question with no success:

There are two linear equations: Ax = b and Ax = b' where b' = ub + v

The equations are scalars.

What can you say about the solutions of both systems:

> A. They have the same solutions
>
> B. They have the same number of solutions
>
> C. Nothing can be said without knowing u and v
>
> D. Nothing can be said without knowing A, u and v

Can someone please help me? (it's very important for me)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27923/290189

Comment: your System is given by $$Ax=b$$ and $$Ax=ub+v$$?

Comment: Are these scalar or vector equations? Can you please edit the question and add math formatting for clarity.

Comment: Yes.
Ax = b and Ax = ub + v.

The equations are scalar, I dont know how to add math formatting but I edit the question and add the scalar remark.